# Check if elements in vector less are than other vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have two `vectors` of `integers`. I want to check if all the first `vector` elements less or equal to their peers in the other `vector`.

```
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v2{8,8,8,8,8};
auto check(true);
for(size_t i=0;i<v1.size();++i){
    if(v1[i]>v2[i]){
        check=false;
        break;
    }  
}
if(check){
    std::cout << "OK";
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it like a std function or somthing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>Lexical order of vector is sufficient:</strike>

```
const bool check = v1 <= v2;
```

You may use (in C++14)

```
const bool ok = std::equal(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1),
                           std::begin(v2), std::end(v2),
                           [](int a, int b)->bool {return a <= b; });
```

In C++11, you have to check `size` manually and remove `std::end(v2)`

Comment: Many Thanks! I thought of it but I did not even try it. I thought it is too luxury to have something like this in C++!!  Thanks Again

Comment: @juanchopanza: You can re-show your answer which was correct contrary to mine as `{1, 9} < {2, 2}`...

Comment: But your first solution is 100% if both sizes are guaranteed  to be equal. isn't it?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: `{1, 9} <= {2, 2}` is true, whereas you expect false.